# How to configure a selector on a relativelayout in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-selector

In an android listview each rowitem that has a relativelayout as its top level view. I want to have a selector on this relativelayout to indicate focused and pressed states. All answers that I have tried still do not work. Is this possible? Here is the code I am using:

```
##my_list_selector
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/my_color_list_selected" />
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_color_list_selected" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/my_color_list_focused" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_color_list_focused" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_color_list_default" />

</selector>

##my_color_list_selected 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:endColor="#21d70076"
      android:startColor="#21d70076"
      android:angle="90"></gradient>
</shape>

##my_color_list_focused 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:endColor="#ffffff"
          android:startColor="#ffffff"
          android:angle="90"></gradient>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#21d70076"/>
</shape>

##my_color_list_default 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
</shape>


## List View

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="top">


    <com.mydemo.app.util.ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_rotate"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/no_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>



##ROW VIEW

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top"        
android:background="@drawable/my_list_selector">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/episode_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_frame"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gridview_row_margins"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/gridview_row_margins"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gridview_row_margins"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_frame"
    android:layout_below="@+id/episode_number"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gridview_row_margins"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/gridview_row_margins"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:
* The issue was resolved unrelated to this code. There was a hard coded background inadvertently being set in the adapater. This code actually does work.

Comment: I can't see how this should be relevant, but i will mention that the list exists in a tab fragment inside a ViewPager

Comment: If you want to post your code as a solution I will try it.